# Call C# unmanaged exports dll with serialPort class from Delphi application

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

I am using Robert Giesecke's Unmanaged Exports to put open method of `SerialPort` class from a C# class into a DLL. For now, the code is:

```cs
[DllExport]
public static void OpenPort(string portName, int baudRate, int dataBits)
{
    SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort
    {
        StopBits = StopBits.One,
        Parity = Parity.None,
        ReadTimeout = 100,
        WriteTimeout = -1,
        PortName = portName,
        BaudRate = baudRate,
        DataBits = dataBits,
    };

    try
    {
        serialPort.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new Exception("aaaaaaaaa");
    }

}
```

When I invoke it in Delphi, the code is:

```pascal
 procedure OpenPort(portName: string; baudRate: integer; dataBits: integer); stdcall;
   external 'TestDll';

procedure TForm3.Button11Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OpenPort('COM2', 19200, 8);
end;
```

But Delphi shows an error:

> External exception E0434352.

What should I do?

Comment: What delphi version?

Comment: It's delphi XE10 Seattle @Blorgbeard

Comment: When i comment the line 'serialPort.Open();', It will be fine in delphi call. So i conclude the exception is thrown by it .

Comment: Delphi string is not the same as .dotnet string

Comment: @MBo So,what should i do? thanks.

Comment: When i modify c# method  to  this , delphi has no error throw ,the code is:[DllExport]
        public static void OpenPort(string portName, int baudRate, int dataBits)
        {
            SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort
            {
                StopBits = StopBits.One,
                Parity = Parity.None,
                ReadTimeout = 100,
                WriteTimeout = -1,
                PortName = "COM2",
                BaudRate = 19200,
                DataBits = 8,
            };
                serialPort.Open();
        }

Comment: You can use BSTR string type (in Delphi - WideString)

Comment: @MBo Ok. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a picky complaint of mine: There is no Delphi XE 10. It's Delphi 10 Seattle. The last XE was XE8.

Comment: @MBo that doesn't match the C# either

Comment: @David Heffernan  c# `BSTR` doesn't match Delphi `Widestring`?

Comment: @Mbo It does. But the C# code uses `string` which here marshals as `UnmanagedType.LPStr`. You'd have to change the Delphi to `WideString` and the C# to `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]`. In my view simpler to use `PAnsiChar`, or `PWideChar`.

Comment: @JerryDodge Ok,ok. You are right. Picky idea is well sometimes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks too.

Comment: OK. I meant that author have to change both C# and Dlp sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two mistakes that can be seen.

1. The first argument in the Delphi import should be declared as `PAnsiChar` to match your DLL. Default marshaling of C# `string` is as a pointer to null terminated array of ANSI characters.
2. Your DLL must not throw an exception. The Delphi code cannot catch it. If you wish to indicate error do so using a boolean or integer return value.

The exception code that you see `E0434352` identifies a .net exception so it is clear that your DLL is indeed throwing an exception which it must not do.

Serial ports are readily accessed with native Delphi code. If this is the only reason for including .net then I think you would be better off dropping it and sticking to Delphi.